# Managing state - chapter 3 of SICP

Tags: haskell, state, sicp, state-monad

I've been working through in [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and completing the exercises in Haskell. The first two chapters were fine (code at [github](https://github.com/chris-taylor/SICP-in-Haskell)) but Chapter 3 is making me think harder.

It starts by talking about managing state, with the example of a bank account. They define a function `make-withdraw` by

```
(define (make-withdraw balance)
    (lambda (amount)
        (if (>= balance amount)
            (begin (set! balance (- balance amount))
                balance)
            "Insufficient funds")))
```

so that you can execute the following code:

```
(define w1 (make-withdraw 100))
(define w2 (make-withdraw 100))

(w1 50)
50

(w2 70)
30

(w2 40)
"Insufficient funds"

(w1 40)
10
```

I'm not sure how I can emulate this in Haskell. I first thought to a some simple function using the State monad:

```
import Control.Monad.State

type Cash    = Float
type Account = State Cash

withdraw :: Cash -> Account (Either String Cash)
withdraw amount = state makewithdrawal where
    makewithdrawal balance = if balance >= amount
        then (Right amount, balance - amount)
        else (Left "Insufficient funds", balance)
```

which allows me to run the code

```
ghci> runState (do { withdraw 50; withdraw 40 }) 100
(Left "Insufficient funds",30.0)
```

but that does something different to the scheme code. Ideally I'd be able to run something like

```
do
  w1 <- makeWithdraw 100
  w2 <- makeWithdraw 100
  x1 <- w1 50
  y1 <- w2 70
  y2 <- w2 40
  x2 <- w1 40
  return [x1,y1,y2,x2]

[Right 50,Right 70,Left "Insufficient funds",Right 40]
```

but I'm not sure how to write the function `makeWithdraw`. Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Scheme code is sneakily using two bits of state: one is the (implicit) association between variables `w1` and `w2` and a ref-cell; the other is the (explicit) state stored in a ref-cell. There's a couple different ways to model this in Haskell. For example, we might pull a similar ref-cell trick with `ST`:

```
makeWithdraw :: Float -> ST s (Float -> ST s (Either String Float))
makeWithdraw initialBalance = do
    refBalance <- newSTRef initialBalance
    return $ \amount -> do
        balance <- readSTRef refBalance
        let balance' = balance - amount
        if balance' < 0
            then return (Left "insufficient funds")
            else writeSTRef refBalance balance' >> return (Right balance')
```

Which lets us do this:

```
*Main> :{
*Main| runST $ do
*Main|   w1 <- makeWithdraw 100
*Main|   w2 <- makeWithdraw 100
*Main|   x1 <- w1 50
*Main|   y1 <- w2 70
*Main|   y2 <- w2 40
*Main|   x2 <- w1 40
*Main|   return [x1,y1,y2,x2]
*Main| :}
[Right 50.0,Right 30.0,Left "insufficient funds",Right 10.0]
```

Another option is to make both pieces of the state explicit, for example by associating each account with a unique `Int` id.

```
type AccountNumber = Int
type Balance = Float
data BankState = BankState
    { nextAccountNumber :: AccountNumber
    , accountBalance :: Map AccountNumber Balance
    }
```

Of course, we would then basically be re-implementing the ref-cell operations:

```
newAccount :: Balance -> State BankState AccountNumber
newAccount balance = do
    next <- gets nextAccountNumber
    modify $ \bs -> bs
        { nextAccountNumber = next + 1
        , accountBalance = insert next balance (accountBalance bs)
        }
    return next

withdraw :: Account -> Balance -> State BankState (Either String Balance)
withdraw account amount = do
    balance <- gets (fromMaybe 0 . lookup account . accountBalance)
    let balance' = balance - amount
    if balance' < 0
        then return (Left "insufficient funds")
        else modify (\bs -> bs { accountBalance = insert account balance' (accountBalance bs) }) >> return (Right balance')
```

Which would then let us write `makeWithdraw`:

```
makeWithDraw :: Balance -> State BankState (Balance -> State BankState (Either String Balance))
makeWithdraw balance = withdraw <$> newAccount balance
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, you have multiple pieces of independent, mutable state here: one for each "account" in the system. The `State` monad only lets you have *one* piece of state. You could store something like `(Int, Map Int Cash)` in the state, incrementing the `Int` to get a fresh key into the map each time, and use that to store the balance... but that's so ugly, isn't it?

Thankfully, however, Haskell has a monad for multiple pieces of independent, mutable state: [`ST`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-ST.html).

```
type Account = ST

makeWithdraw :: Cash -> Account s (Cash -> Account s (Either String Cash))
makeWithdraw amount = do
    cash <- newSTRef amount
    return withdraw
  where
    withdraw balance
        | balance >= amount = do
            modifySTRef cash (subtract amount)
            return $ Right amount
        | otherwise = return $ Left "Insufficient funds"
```

With this, your code example should work fine; just apply [`runST`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-ST.html#v%3arunST) and you should get the list you want. The `ST` monad is pretty simple: you can just create and modify [`STRef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-STRef.html)s, which act just like regular mutable variables; in fact, their interface is basically identical to that of [`IORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-IORef.html)s.

The only tricky bit is the extra `s` type parameter, referred to as the *state thread*. This is used to associate each `STRef` with the `ST` context it's created in. It would be very bad if you could return an `STRef` from an `ST` action, and carry it across to *another* `ST` context — the whole point of `ST` is that you can run it as pure code, outside of `IO`, but if the `STRef`s could escape, you'd have impure, mutable state outside of the monadic context, just by wrapping all your operations in `runST`! So, each `ST` and `STRef` carries around the same `s` type parameter, and `runST` has the type `runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a`. This stops you choosing any particular value for `s`: your code has to work with all possible values of `s`. It's never assigned any particular type; just used as a trick to keep the state threads isolated.